# Why can't I use '.&.' in module

Tags: haskell

I want to test the bit operation in Haskell like this. But it raised error

```hs
module Main where
import Data.Bits
main = print (3 .&. 4)
```

```
Main.hs:8:11: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 23 others
        ...plus 13 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: print (3 .&. 4)
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = print (3 .&. 4)
  |
8 |   main =  print (3 .&. 4)

Main.hs:8:20: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘.&.’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Bits a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Bits Integer -- Defined in ‘Data.Bits’
        instance Bits Bool -- Defined in ‘Data.Bits’
        instance Bits Int -- Defined in ‘Data.Bits’
        ...plus one other
        ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘(3 .&. 4)’
      In the expression: print (3 .&. 4)
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = print (3 .&. 4)
  |
8 |   main =  print (3 .&. 4)
```

When I try this in the GHCI, it works fine. Why does that happened ?

Comment: Maybe sharing the error that it raises would be useful?